# How to record video using Intents?

Tags: java, android

I need to unserstand how I can record video programatically. Now I use this construction:

```
public class AndroidLearningActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent captureVideoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(captureVideoIntent, 100);
    }  

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        Log.e("result", "result:"+resultCode);

    }
}
```

When the application is opened then the camera will be opened too. I have record some video, but if I press "back" button on the device then the application crushes. Please, explain me, how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: You need to post the LogCat/Stacktrace.  How are we meant to know why your application `crushes`?

Comment: looks as you are pressing back key and not sette the intent so data may be null here........log cat needed for confimation

Comment: Yes, you are right, the result is null always. But how should I close the video recording?

Comment: "But how should I close the video recording?" -- that's not a particularly useful question. Some users will press BACK from the video recording activity, whether you like it or not. Hence, you need to handle the case where users press BACK.

Answer (score 1):

looks as you are pressing back key and data (intent) not get set.so data may be null here

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        Log.e("result", "result:"+resultCode);
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in this statement

```
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        Log.e("result", "result:"+resultCode);
```

When you will press back button recording will be cancelled and you will get `data.getData` as null since no recording is done.So change your code to following.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.e("result", "result:" + resultCode);
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Please, tell me, how can I close the standard recording application without back button? There are no ways to do it.

Comment: Yes if you go with using inbuilt recording intent then back button is the only option :)